# Error: No repository for "" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?

Tags: mssql, typeorm

Mi intención es conectar 3 tablas. Con 2 de ellas inicialmente funcionan a la perfección.

```
module.exports = {
"type": "mssql",
"host": "xxx",
"port": 1433,
"username": "xxx",
"password": "xxx",
"database": "xxx",
"entities": [
    "build/models/**/*.js"
]}
```

El problema surge cuando conecto la tercera, que las utiliza como "ManyToOne". Ahí obtengo este error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Entity metadata for Result#RES_ControllerId was not found. Check if you specified a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection options.

Lo soluciono añadiendo __dirname a entities:

```
module.exports = {
"type": "mssql",
"host": "xxx",
"port": 1433,
"username": "xxx",
"password": "xxx",
"database": "xxx",
"entities": [
    __dirname + "build/models/**/*.js"
]}
```

Entonces mi error cambia a:

> No repository for "Tabla1" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?

> No repository for "Tabla2" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?

Llevo varios días atascado aquí sin avanzar hacia delante ni hacia atrás, no hay problema si necesitáis algo más de código. Muchas gracias por adelantado.